# Calculating determinant of Matrix in C++ without creating submatrices

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Is there a way to determine determinant of given matrix in C++ using only one variable (first loaded matrix) and in next recursion functions using only a reference for that matrix?

How to use coordinates of elements in matrix to determine determinants of submatrices of given matrix without creating them as matrices, just using elements in first matrix and their coordinates? Can that be done using recursion or recursion should not be used?

Comment: For any given dimension or for a fixed dimension?

Comment: For any given dimension

Comment: no need to make submatrixes, just use original matriz reference + x1, x2, y1, y2 indexes to know your submatrix bounds

Comment: independent of what you want to do with the submatrices you never need to store them explicitly. All you need is the appropriate transformation from indices into the submatrix to indices into the original matrix

Comment: And what about recursion, can it be used in that process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to calculate a determinant for any matrix of size larger than 3x3 using Cramer's Rule, you're certainly doing something wrong.  Performance will be terrible.

Probably the easiest approach for you to think your way through is to use row reduction to make it into an upper triangular matrix.  Finding the determinant of an upper triangular matrix is easy - just multiply down the diagonal.  As for the rest, just multiply by the constant factors that you used and remember that every swap is a -1.

Comment: Thanks about suggesting that approach!

Comment: @johnydr You're welcome.  It isn't the fastest approach, according to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93501/what-is-the-fastest-numeric-method-for-determinant-calculation that would be to calculate the LU decomposition.  However it is `O(n^3)` and doesn't require a ton of background to understand.